# The IO operation at logical block address for Disk 1 was retried warning after Windows freezes

Tags: windows, windows-10, ssd, motherboard, freeze

I have a Dell XPS 8930 desktop computer that has been freezing intermittently since I got it new. I've tried quite a few remedies, including several fresh installs of Windows, but nothing has worked. Typically, these freezes last only a minute or two, but other times it will go on for 10+ minutes and requires a hard reboot. I have recently noticed that whenever these freezes happen, the following warnings are logged in Windows event viewer immediately after:

[image]

This computer has two drives, one SSD (Disk 1) and one HDD (Disk 0). The error is always for Disk 1. I have seen some solutions on this site mention that replacing the cable to the drive fixed this issue, but this SSD is an M.2 style drive connected using the PCIe slot on the motherboard, so that is not an option. Per other solutions I have also attempted to: change power settings to prevent the drive from turning off; made sure all drivers are up to date; reinstalled Intel RST; nothing has solved the issue.

Two other odd symptoms I have noticed:

- Removing the WiFi/Bluetooth module (which was connected directly to the motherboard) significantly reduced the amount of freezing/lag experienced when playing games.
- I have ended up with corrupted files on **both** drives after experiencing freezes. As far as I know, only files that were actively being read/written to ended up corrupted. Windows is installed on the SSD.

My question is - is this issue likely related to the drive failing, or an issue with the motherboard? I have run `chkdsk C: /r` but it completed with no errors reported, and CrystalDiskInfo says the drive is healthy. I'd like to have concrete evidence for either component before spending money to replace them. The computer is unfortunately not under warranty anymore.

Comment: Backup data on the hard drive to a USB drive and install Windows on the hard drive so that the SSD is not used. If this corrupts / crashes, it would indicate the motherboard.

Comment: If the error is always on Disk 1, you might have a bad disk. I would suggest, if still under warranty, to replace the computer.